# Why does this HTML render differently when properly indented?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list styled into tabular navigation that needs to look like this: [image: Tab example].  To give the tabs rounded corners each tab has left, middle, and right `div` with respective css backgrounds*.

---

When I format the list items like so ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/backus/EXCBZ/)):

```
<li class="tab">
    <div class="item-wrap"><span class="item-before"></span><span class="item"><a href="inventories">Inventory</a></span><span class="item-after"></span></div>
</li>
```

I get the desired result: [image: Properly rendered result]

But when I format the HTML to make it more readable, like so ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/backus/F9dCP/1/)):

```
<li class="tab">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <span class="item-before"></span>
    <span class="item">
      <a href="inventories">Inventory</a>
    </span>
    <span class="item-after"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

The rendering changes: [image: Improperly rendered result]

What is going on?

---

* **Note**: I know that this approach is outdated.  The [class I built this for](http://www.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-spring13/project.php?project=1) restricts us to HTML 4 and CSS 2.

Answer (score 2):

I can't fully explain it, but it is to do with the whitespace around the `a` elements...

This renders correctly...

```
<span class="item"><a href="inventories">Inventory</a></span>
```

This does not...

```
<span class="item"> <a href="inventories">Inventory</a> </span>
```

So reformatting the HTML, introduces whitespace around the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers treat line feeds as whitespace (like literal space character).

Answer (score 1):

It's no secret that HTML condenses multiple whitespace characters into a single space.

However, what's less known is what element that space belongs to.

Consider this HTML: `<b> <i> spaces!</i></b>`

The two spaces arond the `i` element will be condensed, but will the resulting space be inside it, or out?

This difference is what is causing your HTML to render differently when you have different indenting.

Personally, I like to use PHP to echo out HTML like this, so I can have it on multiple lines in the source but only output one line of HTML:

```
<?php
echo "<span>"
    ."Hello, world!"
  ."</span>";
?>
```

Results in:

```
<span>Helld, world!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) teach us:

> By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline
>   elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline
>   elements do not. For information about white space, line breaks, and
>   block formatting, please consult the section on [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html).

And in the cited link

> For all HTML elements except PRE, sequences of white space separate
>   "words" (we use the term "word" here to mean "sequences of non-white
>   space characters"). When formatting text, user agents should identify
>   these words and lay them out according to the conventions of the
>   particular written language (script) and target medium.

So basically, since your elements are defaulted by inline elements, your tags are handled as a "word", and so the spaces between your tags **does counts** when rendering the text.

Basically, at this point, there are two things you might not want:

1. Write all your code at one line
2. Use extra CSS to be able to put the tags in separated lines

Well, at least I would not want this. That is why I use [haml](http://haml.info/) to generate HTML. Like many HTML template engines, it [Allows you to handle white spaces between tags without re-indenting your code](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_)