# Why use 'succeed do' in haml?

Tags: haml

I used html2haml.heroku.com and it turned some ordinary strings into the following:

```
A normal sentence is here
= succeed '.' do
  %strong and it is cut off randomly by this succeed
```

Where the `succeed` call seems unnecessary. Is this just an artifact from the html to haml conversion?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you try

```
A normal sentence is here
= succeed '.' do
  %strong and it is cut off randomly by this succeed
```

and generate the HTML, the output will be like this:

```
A normal sentence is here
<strong>and it is cut off randomly by this succeed</strong>.
```

However, if you try something like

```
A normal sentence is here
%strong and it is cut off randomly by this succeed
.
```

You will have an output like this:

```
A normal sentence is here
<strong>and it is cut off randomly by this succeed</strong>
.
```

And **white spaces are important in inline elements** - please refer to my (late) answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204235/why-does-this-html-render-differently-when-properly-indented/16205456#16205456)

Comment: Good point! I also realized that if you wanted to format part of a word, for example `<b>piece</b>meal` then calling `succeed` will prevent a space between 'piece' and 'meal'